# Реализация интерфейса

Tags: java, польская-запись

Обратная Польская Запись.
Код готов, а как реализовать его на форму? С библиотекой swing не работал (книжки особого пояснения не дают).

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class TranslationInScr {
 public String inPolishNotation(String expression) {
  expression = "(" + expression;
  expression += ")";
  String rezNotation = "";
  final Stack stack = new Stack();
  final Stack outString = new Stack();

  for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
   if (expression.charAt(i) == ')') {
    while (String.valueOf(stack.peek()).charAt(0) != '(') {
     outString.push(stack.pop());
    }

    stack.pop();
   }
   if (expression.charAt(i) == '(') {
    stack.push('(');
   }

   if ((expression.charAt(i) == '+') || (expression.charAt(i) == '-')
     || (expression.charAt(i) == '/') || (expression.charAt(i) == '*')
     || (expression.charAt(i) == '^')) {
    if (stack.size() == 0) {
     stack.push(expression.charAt(i));
    } else if (priority(expression.charAt(i)) > priority(String
      .valueOf(stack.peek()).charAt(0))) {
     stack.push(expression.charAt(i));
    } else {
     while ((stack.size() != 0)
       && (priority(String.valueOf(stack.peek()).charAt(0)) >= priority(expression
         .charAt(i)))) {
      outString.push(stack.pop());
     }
     stack.push(expression.charAt(i));
    }
   } else if (expression.charAt(i) != '(' && expression.charAt(i) != ')')
    outString.push(expression.charAt(i));
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < outString.size(); j++) {
   rezNotation = rezNotation + String.valueOf(outString.get(j));
  }
  return rezNotation;
 }

 private int priority(final char operator) {
  switch (operator) {
  case '^':
   return 4;
  case '*':
   return 3;
  case '/':
   return 3;
  case '-':
   return 2;
  case '+':
   return 2;
  case '(':
   return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: код хоть твой? книжки объяснения не дают? ты их читал?
все зависит от того как тебе это надо отобразить? просто вывести результат? все в картинках и графиках показать? можно просто на консоль, можно в рамочку, фрейм, данные надо вводить или можно в коде просто зашить? 

Comment: первая строка: ввести функцию
вторая строка: запись в опз
кнопка "выполнить"
и лог программы на форме

Comment: ну так это совсем не сложно, это самые основы swing-а, создать JFrame, на нем пару вилдов и баттон, на кнопку элементарный листенер - взять данные с, посчитать, вывести лог и результат...

Comment: У меня нет времени на изучение свинга.. через час нужно показывать все руководству. 
Спасибо хоть на том

Comment: ну если есть хоть минимальные знания программирования, можно быстро все сделать в редакторе, например, нетБинсе

Comment: я не знаю как сделать "что-то", помогите мне сделать "это", я настолько плохо разбираюсь в вопросе что немогу обьяснить "что" мне надо.

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понятно что вам надо. но если просто вывести текст на форму....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout ;
import java.awt.FlowLayout ;

import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JLabel ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame
{

    public TestFrame ()
    {
        super ( "Some title" ) ;
        setSize ( 200, 200 ) ;
        setLayout ( new BorderLayout () ) ;
        setLocationRelativeTo ( null ) ;
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE ) ;

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel ( getDisplayText () ) ;
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel ( new FlowLayout ( FlowLayout.CENTER ) ) ;
        jPanel.add ( jLabel ) ;

        add ( BorderLayout.CENTER, jPanel ) ;
    }

    public String getDisplayText ()
    {
        return "some text to display" ;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        new TestFrame ().setVisible ( true ) ;

    }
}
```